# Alternative solution to HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, background-process, dnx

We are working with .NET Core Web Api, and looking for a lightweight solution to log requests with variable intensity into database, but don't want client's to wait for the saving process.
Unfortunately there's no `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(..)` implemented in `dnx`, and `Task.Run(..)` is not safe.
Is there any elegant solution?

Comment: `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` wasn't safe, either. It was less unsafe than `Task.Run`, but it wasn't safe.

Comment: A good question. I myself am trying to implement a signalR progression reporter (using the IProgress interface) but due to the asynchronous nature of SignalR I need to handle the progress reporting as tasks (albeit very short-lived tasks) without slowing down the operation they are reporting on.

Comment: In case of webapi, you could simply use Response.OnCompleted(Func<Task>) that adds a delegate that will be invoked after the response has completed

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`QueueBackgroundWorkItem` is gone, but we've got `IApplicationLifetime` instead of `IRegisteredObject`, which is being used by the former one. And it looks quite promising for such scenarios, I think.

The idea (and I'm still not quite sure, if it's a pretty bad one; thus, beware!) is to register a singleton, which spawns *and* observes new tasks. Within that singleton we can furthermore register a "stopped event" in order to proper await still running tasks.

This "concept" could be used for short running stuff like logging, mail sending, and the like. Things, that should not take much time, but would produce unnecessary delays for the current request.

```
public class BackgroundPool
{
    protected ILogger<BackgroundPool> Logger { get; }

    public BackgroundPool(ILogger<BackgroundPool> logger, IApplicationLifetime lifetime)
    {
        if (logger == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        if (lifetime == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(lifetime));

        lifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() =>
        {
            lock (currentTasksLock)
            {
                Task.WaitAll(currentTasks.ToArray());
            }

            logger.LogInformation(BackgroundEvents.Close, "Background pool closed.");
        });

        Logger = logger;
    }

    private readonly object currentTasksLock = new object();

    private readonly List<Task> currentTasks = new List<Task>();

    public void SendStuff(Stuff whatever)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            Logger.LogInformation(BackgroundEvents.Send, "Sending stuff...");

            try
            {
                // do THE stuff

                Logger.LogInformation(BackgroundEvents.SendDone, "Send stuff returns.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogError(BackgroundEvents.SendFail, ex, "Send stuff failed.");
            }
        });

        lock (currentTasksLock)
        {
            currentTasks.Add(task);

            currentTasks.RemoveAll(t => t.IsCompleted);
        }
    }
}
```

Such a `BackgroundPool` should be registered as a singleton and can be used by any other component via DI. I'm currently using it for sending mails and it works fine (tested mail sending during app shutdown too).

*Note:* accessing stuff like the current `HttpContext` within the background task should not work. The [old solution](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Hosting/BackgroundWorkScheduler.cs,65) uses `UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem` to prohibit that anyway.

What do you think?

**Update:**

With ASP.NET Core 2.0 there's new stuff for background tasks, which get's better with ASP.NET Core 2.1: [Implementing background tasks in .NET Core 2.x webapps or microservices with IHostedService and the BackgroundService class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice)

Comment: In your ApplicationStopped.Register delegate you don't actually wait for the task returned from "Task.WaitAll(currentTask.ToArray());". Making that call kind of pointless.

Answer (score 29):

As @axelheer mentioned [IHostedService](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2017/11/18/implementing-background-tasks-in-microservices-with-ihostedservice-and-the-backgroundservice-class-net-core-2-x/) is the way to go in .NET Core 2.0 and above.

I needed a lightweight like for like ASP.NET Core replacement for HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem, so I wrote [DalSoft.Hosting.BackgroundQueue](https://github.com/DalSoft/DalSoft.Hosting.BackgroundQueue) which uses.NET Core's 2.0 [IHostedService](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2017/11/18/implementing-background-tasks-in-microservices-with-ihostedservice-and-the-backgroundservice-class-net-core-2-x/).

PM> Install-Package DalSoft.Hosting.BackgroundQueue

In your ASP.NET Core Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddBackgroundQueue(onException:exception =>
   {
                   
   });
}
```

To queue a background Task just add `BackgroundQueue` to your controller's constructor and call `Enqueue`.

```
public EmailController(BackgroundQueue backgroundQueue)
{
   _backgroundQueue = backgroundQueue;
}
    
[HttpPost, Route("/")]
public IActionResult SendEmail([FromBody]emailRequest)
{
   _backgroundQueue.Enqueue(async cancellationToken =>
   {
      await _smtp.SendMailAsync(emailRequest.From, emailRequest.To, request.Body);
   });

   return Ok();
}
```

Comment: is the BackgroundQueue registered as a singleton?

Comment: Yes but I'd look at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker as it does everything my package does and more.

Comment: @DalSoft You mention Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker, but I'm not quite connecting the dots on how that's a _direct_ replacement for `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`. Would you consider posting a new answer describing what that looks like? Thanks!

Comment: @DalSoft yeah am also confused could you shed some light. i get urs but how is Worker " it does everything my package" i dont see it could you explain.

Comment: Sorry guys see [Queued background tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks) MS documentation changed a bit. If you still feel a wrapping library is worthwhile let me know.

Comment: [MS is leaving it up to the end user](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/805) to decide how to implement, so I will continue to support and improve this package.

Comment: Hi, i tried your package, but I still get errors about disposed objects (e.g. IServiceProvider or IConfigurationService) any way to prevent that, or I have to rewrite my code because this is disposed at the end of every request

Comment: @marhyno background tasks operate on their own lifecycle, so you have to scope services as appropriate. For example  the background task could fire after the request has finished. Drop me a GitHub issue if your still having issues.

Answer (score 11):

You can use Hangfire (http://hangfire.io/) for background jobs in .NET Core.

For example :

```
var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(
    () => Console.WriteLine("Fire-and-forget!"));
```

Comment: This solution requires SQL Server. Not that it _can't_ replace some things you might do with `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`, but it's a significantly "heavier" solution which I think is worth mentioning here.

Comment: @ToddMenier Hangfire is able to work with many different storage solutions, including Redis and a new in-memory storage they're working on now.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a tweaked version of [Axel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43183912/80274) that lets you pass in delegates and does more aggressive cleanup of completed tasks.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Example
{
    public class BackgroundPool
    {
        private readonly ILogger<BackgroundPool> _logger;
        private readonly IApplicationLifetime _lifetime;
        private readonly object _currentTasksLock = new object();
        private readonly List<Task> _currentTasks = new List<Task>();

        public BackgroundPool(ILogger<BackgroundPool> logger, IApplicationLifetime lifetime)
        {
            if (logger == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
            if (lifetime == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(lifetime));

            _logger = logger;
            _lifetime = lifetime;

            _lifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() =>
            {
                lock (_currentTasksLock)
                {
                    Task.WaitAll(_currentTasks.ToArray());
                }

                _logger.LogInformation("Background pool closed.");
            });
        }

        public void QueueBackgroundWork(Action action)
        {
#pragma warning disable 1998
            async Task Wrapper() => action();
#pragma warning restore 1998

            QueueBackgroundWork(Wrapper);
        }

        public void QueueBackgroundWork(Func<Task> func)
        {
            var task = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                _logger.LogTrace("Queuing background work.");

                try
                {
                    await func();

                    _logger.LogTrace("Background work returns.");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError(ex.HResult, ex, "Background work failed.");
                }
            }, _lifetime.ApplicationStopped);

            lock (_currentTasksLock)
            {
                _currentTasks.Add(task);
            }

            task.ContinueWith(CleanupOnComplete, _lifetime.ApplicationStopping);
        }

        private void CleanupOnComplete(Task oldTask)
        {
            lock (_currentTasksLock)
            {
                _currentTasks.Remove(oldTask);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just like in Axel's answer you don't actually wait for the task returned from "Task.WaitAll(currentTask.ToArray());".

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little late, but we just ran into this issue too. So after reading lots of ideas, here's the solution we came up with.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Defines a simple interface for scheduling background tasks. Useful for UnitTesting ASP.net code
    /// </summary>
    public interface ITaskScheduler
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Schedules a task which can run in the background, independent of any request.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="workItem">A unit of execution.</param>
        [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Unrestricted = true)]
        void QueueBackgroundWorkItem(Action<CancellationToken> workItem);

        /// <summary>
        /// Schedules a task which can run in the background, independent of any request.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="workItem">A unit of execution.</param>
        [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Unrestricted = true)]
        void QueueBackgroundWorkItem(Func<CancellationToken, Task> workItem);
    }


    public class BackgroundTaskScheduler : BackgroundService, ITaskScheduler
    {
        public BackgroundTaskScheduler(ILogger<BackgroundTaskScheduler> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _logger.LogTrace("BackgroundTaskScheduler Service started.");

            _stoppingToken = stoppingToken;

            _isRunning = true;
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(-1, stoppingToken);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                _isRunning = false;
                _logger.LogTrace("BackgroundTaskScheduler Service stopped.");
            }
        }

        public void QueueBackgroundWorkItem(Action<CancellationToken> workItem)
        {
            if (workItem == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(workItem));
            }

            if (!_isRunning)
                throw new Exception("BackgroundTaskScheduler is not running.");

            _ = Task.Run(() => workItem(_stoppingToken), _stoppingToken);
        }

        public void QueueBackgroundWorkItem(Func<CancellationToken, Task> workItem)
        {
            if (workItem == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(workItem));
            }

            if (!_isRunning)
                throw new Exception("BackgroundTaskScheduler is not running.");

            _ = Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        await workItem(_stoppingToken);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        _logger.LogError(e, "When executing background task.");
                        throw;
                    }
                }, _stoppingToken);
        }

        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private volatile bool _isRunning;
        private CancellationToken _stoppingToken;
    }
```

The `ITaskScheduler` (which we already defined in our old ASP.NET client code for UTest test purposes) allows a client to add a background task. The main purpose of the `BackgroundTaskScheduler` is to capture the stop cancellation token (which is own by the Host) and to pass it into all the background `Task`s; which by definition, runs in the `System.Threading.ThreadPool` so there is no need to create our own.

To configure Hosted Services properly see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62478534/asp-net-core-how-to-register-ihostedservice-which-also-contains-a-custom-interfa/62478535#62478535).

Enjoy!

Comment: This tells work items to stop their work (via CancellationToken), but it doesn't actually ensure any running work items are _complete_ before `ExecuteAsync` finishes, right?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior the code functions just like ASP.NET in that the queued background task(s) will run from start to finish as long as IIS isn't being shut down. If IIS is being shutdown then the cancelation token will be signed and thus all the currently running tasks will be notified.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior one enhancement might be to keep a collection of running tasks and not return from the ExecuteAsync() until all of the currently running tasks have gracefully completed.

Comment: The ASP.NET QueueBackgroundWorkItem uses a [BackgroundWorkScheduler](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web/Hosting/BackgroundWorkScheduler.cs), which goes to a lot of trouble to make sure that its `IRegisteredObject` only gets de-registered after the last running work item gets completed.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has recently posted an article [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio), dated 5/24/2023.  The example [Queued background tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks) is very similar to @Dalsoft's solution.

```
public interface IBackgroundTaskQueue
{
    ValueTask QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask> workItem);

    ValueTask<Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask>> DequeueAsync(
        CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

public class BackgroundTaskQueue : IBackgroundTaskQueue
{
    private readonly Channel<Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask>> _queue;

    public BackgroundTaskQueue(int capacity)
    {
        // Capacity should be set based on the expected application load and
        // number of concurrent threads accessing the queue.            
        // BoundedChannelFullMode.Wait will cause calls to WriteAsync() to return a task,
        // which completes only when space became available. This leads to backpressure,
        // in case too many publishers/calls start accumulating.
        var options = new BoundedChannelOptions(capacity)
        {
            FullMode = BoundedChannelFullMode.Wait
        };
        _queue = Channel.CreateBounded<Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask>>(options);
    }

    public async ValueTask QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(
        Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask> workItem)
    {
        if (workItem == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(workItem));
        }

        await _queue.Writer.WriteAsync(workItem);
    }

    public async ValueTask<Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask>> DequeueAsync(
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var workItem = await _queue.Reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken);

        return workItem;
    }
}


public class QueuedHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<QueuedHostedService> _logger;

    public QueuedHostedService(IBackgroundTaskQueue taskQueue, 
        ILogger<QueuedHostedService> logger)
    {
        TaskQueue = taskQueue;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IBackgroundTaskQueue TaskQueue { get; }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(
            $"Queued Hosted Service is running.{Environment.NewLine}" +
            $"{Environment.NewLine}Tap W to add a work item to the " +
            $"background queue.{Environment.NewLine}");

        await BackgroundProcessing(stoppingToken);
    }

    private async Task BackgroundProcessing(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var workItem = 
                await TaskQueue.DequeueAsync(stoppingToken);

            try
            {
                await workItem(stoppingToken);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, 
                    "Error occurred executing {WorkItem}.", nameof(workItem));
            }
        }
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Queued Hosted Service is stopping.");

        await base.StopAsync(stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) (does not require SQL Server) with the following extension method to easily set up and run a job:

```cs
public static class QuartzUtils
{
        public static async Task<JobKey> CreateSingleJob<JOB>(this IScheduler scheduler,
            string jobName, object data) where JOB : IJob
        {
            var jm = new JobDataMap { { "data", data } };

            var jobKey = new JobKey(jobName);

            await scheduler.ScheduleJob(
                JobBuilder.Create<JOB>()
                .WithIdentity(jobKey)
                .Build(),

                TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity(jobName)
                .UsingJobData(jm)
                .StartNow()
                .Build());

            return jobKey;
        }
}
```

Data is passed as an object that must be serializable. Create an IJob that processes the job like this:

```cs
public class MyJobAsync :IJob
{
   public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
   {
          var data = (MyDataType)context.MergedJobDataMap["data"];
          ....
```

Execute like this:

```cs
await SchedulerInstance.CreateSingleJob<MyJobAsync>("JobTitle 123", myData);
```

Answer (score -5):

The original `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` was a one-liner and very convenient to use.
The "new" way of doing this in ASP Core 2.x requires reading pages of cryptic documentation and writing considerable amount of code.

To avoid this you can use the following alternative method

```
    public static ConcurrentBag<Boolean> bs = new ConcurrentBag<Boolean>();

    [HttpPost("/save")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SaveAsync(dynamic postData)
    {

    var id = (String)postData.id;

    Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    bs.Add(Create(id));
                });

     return new OkResult();

    }


    private Boolean Create(String id)
    {
      /// do work
      return true;
    }
```

The static `ConcurrentBag<Boolean> bs` will hold a reference to the object, this will prevent garbage collector from collecting the task after the controller returns.