# native/canonical approach to Fire-and-forget in ASP.NET Core world

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

Doing some coding with websockets related, I found that's it's unclear at the moment, how to properly deal with long running background processes or tasks executed via fire-and-forget semantics (this is still correct for `ASP.NET Core 2.0`) since there could be some pitfalls with DI scope, app restarting, etc.

So it will be a nice to get some wise ideas how this kind of things need to be implemented in `.NET Core` world without fancy stuff like `Hangfire`

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot that I have a power to close the question as duplicate. Very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36945253/213550

Comment: @VMAtm - This is *not* a duplicate of [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36945253/213550) question.  And after having come across that question and performing half a day of research.  I find this is a very specific and appropriate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was a pretty common question to dotnet team. So they finally write a document explaining how to implement this based on `IHostedService` interface. So since .NET Core 2.0 correct way of implementing this described in this article.

[Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

---

I rewrite my own code with a proposed approach based on queue and queue listener. In many cases, it's really very similar to example proposed in the article, but still, If there will be quite a lot of guys who interested I could extract my solution to GitHub and deploy as a NuGet package.

Comment: Is this available for .netcore ? or should we target .Net Framework 4.x to use `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` ?

Answer (score 6):

It might be worth checking out this MSDN Developer blog on `IHostedService` and the `BackgroundService` class:

- [Implementing background tasks in .NET Core 2.x webapps or microservices with IHostedService and the BackgroundService class](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2017/11/18/implementing-background-tasks-in-microservices-with-ihostedservice-and-the-backgroundservice-class-net-core-2-x/)

**Summary:**

> The `IHostedService` interface provides a convenient way to start
>   background tasks in an ASP.NET Core web application (in .NET Core 2.0)
>   or in any process/host (starting in .NET Core 2.1 with `IHost`). Its
>   main benefit is the opportunity you get with the graceful cancellation
>   to clean-up code of your background tasks when the host itself is
>   shutting down.

Answer (score 0):

I am researching this for days. I have a similar question here:

[Asp.Net Core 2.0: Simple way to execute long running tasks and report progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45950588/asp-net-core-2-0-simple-way-to-execute-long-running-tasks-and-report-progress)

I have found an approach that uses **QueueBackgroundWorkItem**, but this is not available in Asp.Net Core.

The only thing I have found to be consistent in people's answers is that fire-and-forget is something that needs to be done outside IIS. In a **Windows Service** or something like **Azure Web Jobs**.

The only thing simple that free you from having to implement a distributed architecture is **Hangfire**, but it seems to be unrecommended for critical operations.