# Asp.Net Core 2.0: Simple way to execute long running tasks and report progress?

Tags: angular, signalr, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a page where the user can select multiple files and upload them.

Once the files are buffered in the server, they are deserialized, and the object graphs are stored using Entity Framework Core 2 and SQL Server.

All this happens within a controller action.

The problem is that when the file is a little bit bigger, this collection of tasks can take about 5 minutes to complete, and because of that, I get a 502 error (probably a timeout).

To solve this problem, I had the idea of reporting progress. So it would prevent the timeout. I researched, and some people suggested using SignalR. But I've found out that SignalR is not yet available for Asp.Net Core.

So how can I solve this issue in a basic way? I would like to report progress from my controller action. But if this is complicated stuff to do, then how can I prevent the timeout from happening?

I am using Angular 4.3.5 by the way.

Comment: If push-based system cannot be done, you can always retreat back to pull-based solution: make an endpoint to let client code poke it and get back the progress. Not necessarily advocating for it though.

Comment: Did you check this? https://chsakell.com/2016/10/10/real-time-applications-using-asp-net-core-signalr-angular/

Comment: Yes I did. But he is using an alpha version of signalr. I am a little bit afraid of using something unstable. Perhaps I will give it a try If no other options appear.

Comment: @JacksonMourão Is there any article regarding aspnetcore 2.0 - sql reports integration ?

Comment: Sorry. I don't know.