# Asp.net core How to Register IHostedService which also Contains a Custom Interface

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, ihostedservice

How do I property register an class which contains both the `IHostedService` and a custom interface like `IMyInterface`?

As in

`class BackgroundTaskScheduler : BackgroundService, ITaskScheduler {...}`

If it is configure like:

```
services.AddHostedService<BackgroundTaskScheduler>();
```

And then try to have it inject into a client, like so:

```
public class Foo
{
    Foo(ITaskScheduler taskScheduler) {...}
}
```

An error is generated stating that ASP.net can't resolve `BackgroundTaskScheduler`, why?

Answer (score 6):

After reading lots of ideas, including:

- [AddHostedService() registers service as Transient](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/553) - which I agree with most of the complains, since most hosted services don't live and/or run in isolation.
- [How to inject a reference to a specific IHostedService implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51254053/how-to-inject-a-reference-to-a-specific-ihostedservice-implementation) - which suggested a unique concept of using a hidden `HostedServicewrapping` class which forward the start and stop calls to the real hosted service.

But how to get it to work without requiring a wrapper class? I combined the ideas discussed above into the following two extension methods.

#### Interface Dependency Injection

If you like using interface DI, as in `Bar.Bar(IFoo foo)` then use this one:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Used to register <see cref="IHostedService"/> class which defines an referenced <typeparamref name="TInterface"/> interface.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TInterface">The interface other components will use</typeparam>
        /// <typeparam name="TService">The actual <see cref="IHostedService"/> service.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="services"></param>
        public static void AddHostedApiService<TInterface, TService>(this IServiceCollection services)
            where TInterface : class
            where TService : class, IHostedService, TInterface
        {
            services.AddSingleton<TInterface, TService>();
            services.AddSingleton<IHostedService>(p => (TService) p.GetService<TInterface>());
        }
```

Usage:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHostedApiService<ITaskScheduler, BackgroundTaskScheduler>();
        }
```

#### Concrete class Dependency Injection

If you like to use concrete class injection, as in `Bar.Bar(Foo foo)` then use:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Used to register <see cref="IHostedService"/> class which defines an interface but will reference the <typeparamref name="TService"/> directly.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TService">The actual <see cref="IHostedService"/> service.</typeparam>
        public static void AddHostedApiService<TService>(this IServiceCollection services)
            where TService : class, IHostedService
        {
            services.AddSingleton<TService>();
            services.AddSingleton<IHostedService>(p => p.GetService<TService>());
        }
```

Usage:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHostedApiService<BackgroundTaskScheduler>();
        }
```

Enjoy!